# How to run a loop where I change i and k at the same time in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have two objects:

```
ElectionDay <- c( "1982-11-02",
                  "1984-11-06",
                  "1986-11-04")
```

And

```
ElectionYear <- seq(from=1982, to=1986, by = 2)
```

I want to run a for loop that changes i and k at the same rate. This is what i have so far and i know it is wrong.

```
for (i in ElectionDay){
for (k in ElectionYear){
print(i); print(k)

}}
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
1982; "1982-11-02"
1984; "1984-11-06"
1986; "1986-11-04"
```

I do not want it to cycle back around where it runs all of i for each value of k like it would in a normal loop.

Comment: What do you mean *changes i and k at the same rate*? Maybe you are looking for `ElectionYear[match(gsub('-.*', '', ElectionDay), ElectionYear)]`?

Comment: In your code `k` is not defined. You can extract the year from the date.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cat` and `paste0` in the loop.

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  cat(paste0(ElectionYear[i], ";"), paste0('"', ElectionDay[i], '"'), "\n")
}
```

The `\n` gives the new line.

As @markus pointed out we can avoid the `for` loop by doing:

```
cat(paste(ElectionYear, paste0('"', ElectionDay, '"'), sep = "; "), sep = "\n")
```

**Result**

```
1982; "1982-11-02" 
1984; "1984-11-06" 
1986; "1986-11-04"
```

Comment: An option to avoid the loop that you might want to add in your answer is `cat(paste(ElectionYear, ElectionDay, sep = " ; "), sep = "\n")`

Comment: The `sep="\n"` is neat, thanks!! The quotes were missing though.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, everyone, for your helpful replies!

Answer (score 0):

There´re several ways to do it. But firstly you have to indicate *from...to* you want to interate, so it'd be `1:length(ElectionDay)` part.

You can use `lubridate` to paste the year of your `ElectionDay` object and then use it inside the loop.

```
library(lubridate)

ElectionDay <- c( "1982-11-02",
                  "1984-11-06",
                  "1986-11-04")

for (i in 1:length(ElectionDay)){
  print(paste(year(ElectionDay[i]), ";", ElectionDay[i]))
}
```

which returns:

```
#[1] "1982 ; 1982-11-02"
#[1] "1984 ; 1984-11-06"
#[1] "1986 ; 1986-11-04"
```

If you want to unquote the years and semicolon, you can use `cat` instead, as @jay.sf said:

```
for (i in 1:length(ElectionDay)){
  cat(paste0(year(ElectionDay[i])), ";", paste0('"', ElectionDay[i], '"'), "\n")
}


#1982 ; "1982-11-02" 
#1984 ; "1982-11-02" 
#1986 ; "1982-11-02"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with `mapply`:

```
a <- mapply(function(i,k){
  print(i)
  print(k)
}, ElectionDay, ElectionYear)
```

`mapply` takes vectors and calls a function with each element of the vectors as arguments. (The assignment to `a` is just to supress output of `mapply`)